# legends position multiplot gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am using Windows 10 and Gnuplot 5.0. 
I have a script to plot several graphs simultaneously:

```
GNUTERM = "wxt"
set terminal wxt
set termoption enhanced
set encoding iso_8859_1
set multiplot layout 1,3
set xtics out
set ytics out
set xtics nomirror
set ytics nomirror
set xzeroaxis linetype 2 linewidth 1.5
show xzeroaxis
# Graph1
set key center right
set xrange [3.3:9.0]
set yrange [-0.1:1.10]
set title "Title 1"
set xlabel "x"
set ylabel "y"
plot \
"results_1.dat" u 1:2:4 title "exp." with e pointtype 9 pointsize 0.5 linecolor rgb "red" , \
"results_1.dat" u 1:3 title "fit." with line linecolor rgb "black" linewidth 2 dashtype 2 smooth bezier
# Graph2
set xrange [3.3:9.0]
set yrange [-0.1:1.10]
set key top right
set title "Title 2"
set xlabel "x"
set ylabel "y"
plot \
"results_2.dat" u 1:2:4 title "exp." with e pointtype 9 pointsize 0.5 linecolor rgb "blue", \
"results_2.dat" u 1:3 title "fit." with line linecolor rgb "black" linewidth 2 dashtype 2 smooth bezier
# Graph3
set xrange [3.3:9.0]
set yrange [-0.1:1.10]
set key outside vertical top right
set title "Title 3"
set xlabel "x"
set ylabel "y
plot \
"results_3.dat" u 1:2:4 title "exp." with e pointtype 9 linecolor rgb "red", \
"results_3.dat" u 1:3 title "fit." with line linecolor rgb "black" linewidth 2 dashtype 2 smooth bezier
unset multiplot
pause 3
reread
```

However, instead of getting the legend outside only for the graph 3, all legends are shown outside the graphs (see attached image)

[image: plot gnuplot]

I want legends 1 and 2 inside the graphs and legend 3 outside. What's wrong in my script?

Any help is appreciated.

Supernono06

Comment: Give us your data files! But yo may try `set key inside` yourself first.

Comment: Indeed, it works thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say without being able to run your script, but if I had to guess I'd say that you request the legend to be outside for graph 3, and when you `reread` the script you don't put it back inside. Try something like

```
set key inside center top
```

for the first graph (or add a `reset` statement to the beginning of your script).